# show/hide panel according to metric from Prometheus in grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I saw examples of variables but this is not what I am looking for.
I have the following scenario:
metric can return the following:

1. go_metric{val1="true"}
2. go_metric{val1="false"}

I want to add panel to my dashboard only if the "true" value returns.

How can I achieve this?